# add task to taskmanager with xml and schtasks in C#

Tags: c#, xml, arguments, command-prompt, windows-task-scheduler

I want to create a new Task for the task manager programmatically in c#.
But I need to add arguments to the task. Say "myProg.exe -doSomething".
So far I did find any solution to add arguments using a normal schtasks command line (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
Therefor I figured I could create an XML and import it.

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>mldz</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-02-12T20:01:00</StartBoundary>
      <EndBoundary>2015-02-13T16:44:04.324784</EndBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
      <UserId>User-PC\myusername</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveTokenOrPassword</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>PT0S</DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>myapp.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-doSomething</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory></WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

using the example on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722156.aspx
I tried to import the xml file (saved in "C:\test\test.xml")

schtasks /Create /s "USER-PC" /u "muusername" /p "mypassword" /xml "c:\test\task.xml" /tn "from xml"

But I got this error:
ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.

I tried it like this:
schtasks /Create /s "USER-PC" /xml "c:\test\task.xml" /tn "from xml"

but I got this error
ERROR: Access is denied.

so I tried

C:\Users\mldz>schtasks /Create /s "USER-PC" /ru "myusername" /rp "mypassword" /xml "c:\test\task.xml" /tn "uit xml"

but again:
ERROR: Access is denied.

How can I import an xml file to the task manager? or add arguments in a command like this:

`schtasks /create /sc once /tn myTask /tr "MyApp.exe -backup" /st 20:01 /F /Z /V1 /rp "mypassword" /ru "mydomain\myusername"`

Answer (score 1):

The `/U` and `/P` parameters are specifically what will give you access to the server so you can **CREATE** the task.  Not what you need to **RUN** the task.  If the credentials you're giving in your example are specifically the account under which you want to run the task, then you need to use the `/RU` and `/RP` parameters instead.

Credit for this answer goes to [thebackroomtech.com](http://thebackroomtech.com/2009/04/06/windows-2008-schtasks-error-user-credentials-are-not-allowed-on-the-local-machine/).  I was doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

`schtasks /create /tn startMyApp /tr "myapp.exe -dowork" /sc once /st 16:50 /f`

> SUCCESS: The scheduled task "startMyApp" has successfully been
>   created.

create ;-) seems leaving out the /z in V1 was the trick to add the arguments.

But still, if there's anyone who can help my out with the xml issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with powershell 2.0 or higher. Not C# but easily adapted.

```
$taskname = 'mytask'
$taskpath = 'mypath'
$schtasks = 'c:\windows\system32\schtasks.exe'
$compname = ($env:COMPUTERNAME)
$xmlfile = 'c:\mydirectory\tasks\mytask.xml'
$principal = "mydomain\myuser"
$password = 'mypassword'
$tn = "$taskpath\$taskname"
Invoke-Expression "& $schtasks /create /s $compname /ru $principal /rp $password /xml $xmlfile /tn $tn /f"
```

schtasks.exe is limited. There are some parameters it cannot configure unless you use xml. I created the task in the GUI then exported it to xml. (note: to deploy with GPO users need to be local admins.